# Open-access journals in Computational Science

Tags: publications

In light of the recent [petition to boycott Elsevier](http://thecostofknowledge.com/), I was wondering what options we have in Computational Science for

- Journals which are completely open-access,
- Journals which allow/support open-access articles.

I am aware that there are quite a few sub-areas in Computational Science, each with their own set of specialized publications, but I'm looking for alternatives to more general venues such as the Journal of Computational Physics or the Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics.

Comment: Anyone commenting/posting on this question: **please** look at [this question about journals on Meta](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/166/are-questions-about-lists-of-journals-allowed) and vote/answer/comment so that we can figure out how to best pose questions about journals, if questions like this one fit the Stack Exchange format, and if we want these types of questions.

Comment: I really like Plos Computational Biology

Answer (score 11):

**The boycott of Elsevier should not be mistaken as a push for open access journals**.  The phrase "open access" does not appear in any of the reasons given for the boycott at http://thecostofknowledge.com.  Rather, the reasons are:

1. High prices
2. Bundling
3. Elsevier's support for SOPA and similar efforts

Note that **many open access journals run by commercial publishers also charge high prices**; they just charge them to authors instead of readers.

Very many journals allow one to put pre- and post-prints of articles on [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) or institutional servers, thus providing open access without the need to charge high fees to authors.  [Sherpa/RoMEO](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/index.php) has a searchable database of journals' policies on archiving pre-/post-prints.  For instance, all [SIAM journals](http://epubs.siam.org/) are "green", meaning that they allow archiving of both pre- and post-print versions.  They also have [low subscription prices](http://www.siam.org/journals/prices.php).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to conflate the two. I was just wondering what journals are on the other side of the divide.

Answer (score -1):

Hindawi Publishing has a couple:

http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ana/

http://www.hindawi.com/journals/cmmm/

http://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/

But for all these "open access" journals, the authors pay a substantial "article processing charge".

I haven't checked their "rating", though.

Comment: Hindawi is on Beall's ["watchlist"](http://metadata.posterous.com/83235355) for being a borderline predatory open access publisher.

Comment: @GertVdE: In light of the discussion on Meta [here](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/166/are-questions-about-lists-of-journals-allowed), could you please flesh out your answer with why one might submit to these open access journals?

Comment: @AndrewT.Barker: It's not clear from the article what the problem with Hindawi is. The most concrete statement was "This publisher has way too many journals than can be properly handled by one publisher". It would be interesting (though probably offtopic here) if people who have bad experiences with this publising group to say so.